# System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery cookieToken

Tags: asp.net, security

can anybody explain what exactly the cookieToken parameter is when I call the function in MVC: AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
Is it possible to use the cookieToken as a Session identifier to identify the user and current session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

ASP.Net generates a random [Cross-site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A8-Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) Token on every request (even for the same user).  You can verify this by going to your website and looking at the source.  There will be a hidden field "__RequestVerificationToken" that will contain a string of random letters and numbers.  When you refresh the page it will randomly generate a new set of letters and numbers.

This is not to identify a user to a particular session, but to identify a user to a single request.

To read more on CSRF attacks to understand the purpose of this token, read [OWASP's Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10) on [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A8-Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))